# Generating a non-standard normal distribution from existing data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

Given a non-standard normal distribution in a pandas dataframe with sample size 'n', is there a reliable method to generate/simulate another distribution (with user specified sample size) with the same moments as the original distribution?

**What I have...**

```
import pandas as pd

row_list = [{"Bin": 1,"Value": 0,}, {"Bin": 2,"Value": 0,}, {"Bin": 3,"Value": 1,}, {"Bin": 4,"Value": 12,},    {"Bin": 5,"Value": 24,},    {"Bin": 6,"Value": 89,},    {"Bin": 7,"Value": 203,},   {"Bin": 8,"Value": 460,},   {"Bin": 9,"Value": 884,},   {"Bin": 10,"Value": 1539,}, {"Bin": 11,"Value": 2638,}, {"Bin": 12,"Value": 4278,}, {"Bin": 13,"Value": 6446,}, {"Bin": 14,"Value": 8942,}, {"Bin": 15,"Value": 11990,},    {"Bin": 16,"Value": 15484,},    {"Bin": 17,"Value": 18791,},    {"Bin": 18,"Value": 22449,},    {"Bin": 19,"Value": 25985,},    {"Bin": 20,"Value": 29209,},    {"Bin": 21,"Value": 32027,},    {"Bin": 22,"Value": 33812,},    {"Bin": 23,"Value": 35048,},    {"Bin": 24,"Value": 36089,},    {"Bin": 25,"Value": 36512,},    {"Bin": 26,"Value": 35993,},    {"Bin": 27,"Value": 35890,},    {"Bin": 28,"Value": 33990,},    {"Bin": 29,"Value": 32915,},    {"Bin": 30,"Value": 31471,},    {"Bin": 31,"Value": 29438,},    {"Bin": 32,"Value": 27672,},    {"Bin": 33,"Value": 25154,},    {"Bin": 34,"Value": 23347,},    {"Bin": 35,"Value": 21283,},    {"Bin": 36,"Value": 19520,},    {"Bin": 37,"Value": 17730,},    {"Bin": 38,"Value": 15732,},    {"Bin": 39,"Value": 14380,},    {"Bin": 40,"Value": 12665,},    {"Bin": 41,"Value": 11182,},    {"Bin": 42,"Value": 9839,}, {"Bin": 43,"Value": 8846,}, {"Bin": 44,"Value": 7736,}, {"Bin": 45,"Value": 6653,}, {"Bin": 46,"Value": 5829,}, {"Bin": 47,"Value": 5153,}, {"Bin": 48,"Value": 4368,}, {"Bin": 49,"Value": 3752,}, {"Bin": 50,"Value": 3397,}, {"Bin": 51,"Value": 2790,}, {"Bin": 52,"Value": 2415,}, {"Bin": 53,"Value": 2079,}, {"Bin": 54,"Value": 1779,}, {"Bin": 55,"Value": 1508,}, {"Bin": 56,"Value": 1302,}, {"Bin": 57,"Value": 1087,}, {"Bin": 58,"Value": 899,},  {"Bin": 59,"Value": 790,},  {"Bin": 60,"Value": 731,},  {"Bin": 61,"Value": 638,},  {"Bin": 62,"Value": 486,},  {"Bin": 63,"Value": 464,},  {"Bin": 64,"Value": 415,},  {"Bin": 65,"Value": 328,},  {"Bin": 66,"Value": 255,},  {"Bin": 67,"Value": 227,},  {"Bin": 68,"Value": 187,},  {"Bin": 69,"Value": 182,},  {"Bin": 70,"Value": 123,},  {"Bin": 71,"Value": 141,},  {"Bin": 72,"Value": 112,},  {"Bin": 73,"Value": 101,},  {"Bin": 74,"Value": 84,},   {"Bin": 75,"Value": 71,},   {"Bin": 76,"Value": 60,},   {"Bin": 77,"Value": 38,},   {"Bin": 78,"Value": 43,},   {"Bin": 79,"Value": 51,},   {"Bin": 80,"Value": 27,},   {"Bin": 81,"Value": 15,},   {"Bin": 82,"Value": 25,},   {"Bin": 83,"Value": 23,},   {"Bin": 84,"Value": 14,},   {"Bin": 85,"Value": 13,},   {"Bin": 86,"Value": 13,},   {"Bin": 87,"Value": 7,},    {"Bin": 88,"Value": 12,},   {"Bin": 89,"Value": 13,},   {"Bin": 90,"Value": 8,},    {"Bin": 91,"Value": 11,},   {"Bin": 92,"Value": 3,},    {"Bin": 93,"Value": 5,},    {"Bin": 94,"Value": 2,},    {"Bin": 95,"Value": 1,},    {"Bin": 96,"Value": 2,},    {"Bin": 97,"Value": 0,},    {"Bin": 98,"Value": 3,},    {"Bin": 99,"Value": 2,},    {"Bin": 100,"Value": 0,},   {"Bin": 101,"Value": 0,},   {"Bin": 102,"Value": 0,},   {"Bin": 103,"Value": 0,},   {"Bin": 104,"Value": 0,},   {"Bin": 105,"Value": 0,}]


df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)

# df.shape = (105, 2)
```

**Input data example plot (Bin vs Value)**
[image: Bin vs Value]

**What I'd like to generate...**

```
# gather moments (mvsk) of this data set
mean = df["Value"].mean()
var = df["Value"].var()
skew = df["Value"].skew()
kurt = df["Value"].kurt()

input_sample_size = sum(df["Value"]) # ~786K

desired_sample_size = 100e6 # 100 million


# This is where I seek help...
new_distribution = generate_dist(mean, var, skew, kurt, desired_sample_size)
```

Essentially, my goal is to simulate a much much larger distribution having the same characteristics of the original distribution. The output plot would thus look largely similar to the input one except that it would have a lot more `Bins`.

Side note: I'm expecting all my incoming data to have positive skewness and long tails.

Comment: maybe you look into scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)